# How to create a job including JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, api, crowdflower

I am using the [CrowdFlower builder API](https://crowdflower.com/docs/api).

When I try to create a job sending an HTTP POST request to `CrowdFlower` with JavaScript code in the `'js'` attribute, `CrowdFlower` creates the job but *the JavaScript code is not properly parsed*.

I realised that the problem is that `CrowdFlower` does not parse the `';'` character.

I have this problem even with a simple variable assignment.

I tried sending the `HTTP POST` request from my Java code as well as from [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/restclient/) and it did not work.

Did somebody manage to include JavaScript code when using the `CrowdFlower` builder API?